# Error "#1118 - row size too large" on the first row of the table only

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, update, errors

I ran into a problem using a mySQL database. I have some columns as type text but when I try to enter data into the first row I get the error code *"#1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs"* for anything with more than 15 characters. This only occurs for the first row, all the other rows in the column and table work just fine. Help!

```
Field Type    Collation              Null   Default  Extra  
pid   int(11)                        No     None     AUTO_INCREMENT             
3     text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
6     text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
7     text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
8     text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
9     text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
10    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
21    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
22    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
23    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
24    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
25    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
26    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
27    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
28    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
29    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
30    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
31    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
32    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
33    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
34    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
35    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
36    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
37    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
38    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
39    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
40    text    utf8_general_ci        Yes    NULL                                
... 41-59 follow
```

Indexes:

```
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Field   Cardinality Collation   Null    
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes     No      pid     61          A
```

Server Version: 5.5.9

Comment: Don't get distracted by the fact that you're using `TEXT` columns and the error message mentions `TEXT` columns...  To identify this problem, you need to look at all of the *other* columns, the ones that aren't `TEXT`, which aren't currently shown in the output above.  It's not likely these text columns that are causing the problem -- even if updating one of them triggers the error -- it's something in one of the other columns that's pushing the row size over the ~8000 byte limit for InnoDB.  Post all of the columns, please.

Comment: Those are all of the columns, and if any other columns were added they would be text as well.

Comment: Ah, sorry, since there are some skipped numbers, I assumed you had omitted some columns.  What is the major/minor/release version of your server? (e.g., 5.1.67)

Comment: Thats the version I think.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested from [**this bug report**](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63507), you may need to look into the following:

## File Format

- Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_format%';`

  - [innodb_file_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format)
  - [innodb_file_format_max](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format_max)
- You might see values `Antelope`, `Barracuda`

## Row Format

- Run `ALTER TABLE tblname ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;` to [make the row format Dynamic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dynamic-format.html)
- Run `ALTER TABLE tblname ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;` to [make the row format Compressed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/compressed-format.html)

## Suggestions

Workaround: use new InnoDB file format Barracuda and row_format=DYNAMIC

This was added to the change log in MySQL 5.5.29

Perhaps an upgrade to the latest MySQL 5.5. is in order

Give it a Try !!!